# create-react-app приводит SyntaxError: missing : after property id при запуске в firefox 44

Tags: reactjs, firefox, create-react-app

Запуск нового приложения через create-react-app приводит к ошибке:

> SyntaxError: missing : after property id   местоположение:
>   0.chunk.js:14:12

Мне нужно, чтобы была поддержка `ff 44+`. На chrome все (конечно же) хорошо.

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось все просто: в нашем  `package.json` дополнительно прописываем наш входной файл js: `"main": "index.js"`

плюс [вот здесь](https://www.andreasreiterer.at/fix-whitescreen-static-react-app/) неплохо описано, как избавится от других проблем с загрузкой скриптов

Answer (score 0):

на всякий случай добавлю, что для тех кто будет работать c firefox 44+ нужно дополнительно установить  "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3"

и собирать проект вручную без помощи create-react-app, на medium много статей на эту тему